# Get Data From Email Template Merge fields in Lightning Application

Tags: email-template, lightning-apps

I have created one Lightning application which has form with lightning checkboxes and lightning input. The application has `salesOrderId` which is field of `SBQQ__Quote__c(Quote)` object. I have Use Template picklist which fetch's all the email templates based on folder name. when user selects any of the templates it gets the Body & Subject from Email template and display's on the lightning application.

[image: aopsEmailTemplateApp]

Now Subject & Body are rendered with merged fields and I need to show data instead of merge fields.
So till now I know that we can read entire string and break merge fields and separate object & fields, but I need to get data from Quote object which has lookup to Contact, Account & Opportunity all merge fields used below. Breaking merge fields would only give me Account=>Name not the lookup field name on Quote.

So is it possible to display data from `SBQQ__Quote__c(Quote)` using Merge fields. Hard part would be to get lookup relationship field names from Quote object with given Merge fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Messaging.renderEmailTemplate` to accomplish this task. It accepts a `whoId`, `whatId`, and one or more email `bodies` to render (the parameters are `Id`, `Id`, and `List<String>`, respectively). This operation consumes a SOQL query, but will take care of all the hard work of merging data for you.

Comment: Nice @sfdcfox but I need to pass Account, contact & opportunity id here and we have only WhoId for contact & whatid for Account

Comment: And in case of Whoid also i need to pass Contact & User

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Did you even try this method before dismissing this as useless? Just pass in the Contact and Opportunity and see how well it works.

Comment: i never said its useless where did i ever mention it?? and by the way yes i tried it when i am passing Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(quoLst[0].SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c,quoLst[0].SBQQ__Account__c,new List<String>{emailTempList[0].body}); i am not getting data where account is having merge field

Comment: Please mind what your saying.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal I meant no offense, I guess it sounded different in my mind. My apologies. That said, you could have mentioned more details upfront. Have you tried your template using the standard email app in Salesforce or tried using Test Merge Fields from the template? How does it behave there?

Comment: It worked my bad.Sorry.!! There were some issues in my code. So i need to just pass contact & Opportunity id rest all will be taken care?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Yes, that's all you need.

Comment: Done thanks for the Help as always @sfdcfox!!!